# Папка для библиотек в Django проекте

Tags: python, django

Хост для моего джанго проекта не разрешает мне ставить свои библиотеки в python. До этого я просто кидал пакеты в корень проекта, но сейчас дело подходит к релизу и хотелось бы это все поместить в отдельную папку libs и добавить в sys.path.

На боевом сервере можно написать в wsgi-файл добавление пути. Но для разработки я использую встроенный сервер (manage.py runserver).

Вопрос собственно в том, где написать это добавление, что бы оно выполнялось не зависимо от используемого сервера?

Пробовал:

```
project/settings.py
project/__init__.py
```

не работает

PS.
Дела обстоят ещё хуже в traceback'e в pyton_path есть мой путь но всеравно import error

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.3.4
Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Could not import building.views. Error was: No module named pisa.ho
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _get_callback, line 167
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/butek/git/ucrm/lib',
 '/home/butek/git/ucrm',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
```

библиотека лежит в папке '/home/butek/git/ucrm/lib'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извиняюсь была ошибка в коде импорта библиотеки. Вопрос снят.

PS. Путь добавил в project/**init**.py
вроде работает